# Problem in showing the block would execute SHM

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, harmonic-oscillator

> A block of mass m is suspended from the ceiling of a stationary standing elevator through a spring constant k. Suddenly the cable breaks and the elevator starts falling freely. Show that the block now executes a simple harmonic motion of amplitude mg/k

The problem here is when working in frame of reference of the elevator the equation comes out to be

Weight-psuedo force-kx=0

i.e mg-mg-kx=0

According to the equation Kx=0 so how does it execute SHM; what's wrong here?

Comment: When the elevator is stationary the string is extended by mg-kx=0
In freefall there is no gravitational force. mg-kx=0 therefore is the initial condition describing spring extension x.
A spring thus extended and then released will oscilate in length about it's unextended and uncontracted length. You have to consider the mass as you would the mass of a pendulum.
(should have been an answer not a comment)

Answer (score 1):

When the elevator is stationary the string is extended by mg-kx=0 In freefall there is no gravitational force. mg-kx=0 therefore is the initial condition describing spring extension x. A spring thus extended and then released will oscilate in length about it's unextended and uncontracted length. You have to consider the mass as you would the mass of a pendulum.

Answer (score 0):

In the stationary elevator the extension of the spring from its equilibrium length is $\frac{mg}{k}$ and this is the initial condition of the spring.

When the elevator and its contents are in free fall the effective gravitational field strength is zero your equation of motion should have been

weight-pseudo force-kx=ma

assuming that down is positive, $x$ is the downward extension of the spring and $a$ is the acceleration of the mass.

$mg-mg-kx=ma \Rightarrow -kx=ma$ which is the equation of shm you are looking for with amplitude (the initial condition) $\frac{mg}{k}$.

Comment: But doesn't a(acceleration) has to be zero because in the frame of the lift it's not accelerating and we have already applied psuedo force that's is mg upwards!

Comment: The mass is accelerating in the lift frame because it has a force exerted on it by the spring. In effect you are doing the experiment in outer space with no gravitational forces present.  For example if you dropped soething in the lift it would not move relative to the lift.  An observer on the Earth would see the object you dropped and the lift accelerating downwards at the same rate - $g$.